# Fetched results in imap2 to display in console

Tags: linux, shell, imap, telnet

I have made a script that connects to a imap server and then sends different messages,in order ot get the first mail[i only need the first one].
When I run the script I get no results but when i type the same last command in the terminal I get a result.

Any idea how to fix this?

MY script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#!/bin/bash
set password 'ent'
spawn telnet host imap2
send "1 login picard enterprise\r"
send "2 list '' '*'\r"
expect "*"

send "3  EXAMINE INBOX\r"
send "4 fetch 1 all\r"

send "5 fetch 1 body[]\r"
```

As I said before ,when I type `5 fetch 1 body[]` in terminal i get some output but the script shows nothing.any ideas?

Comment: I've always used longer tags in IMAP (`A001 login ...` instead of `1 login ...`) to allow script to wait for command completion. Could you try `send "A005 FETCH 1 BODY[]\r\n"` `expect "A005"`

Comment: You can call this cheating but if you really want IMAP access in `except` you can use the `imap4` package for Tcl (`expect` scripts are just Tcl code): http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/tcllib/imap4/imap4.html#section3. You will need to install Tcllib if you don't have it already installed but as a bonus you could also get better security by using TLS (see the top of the page I've linked to).

Answer (score 1):

Your script has several syntax errors and I do not think you've made any attempt at researching IMAP syntax at all.

```
send "1 login picard enterprise\r"
```

This is correct provided that the login and password don't contain spaces or other odd characters, and that Expect actually sends \r\n when you type \r there.

```
send "2 list '' '*'\r"
```

`''` is not IMAP, IMAP uses `""`.

```
send "3  EXAMINE INBOX\r"
```

You have one space too many after the 3. Spaces aren't idempotent in IMAP; if the protocol says to use one space you have to use exactly one, neither more nor less.

```
send "4 fetch 1 all\r"
send "5 fetch 1 body[]\r"
```

[`ALL` and `BODY[]` overlap](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5), why do you send both? You could just send `4 FETCH 1 (FLAGS INTERNALDATE BODY[])` and get the same data without repetition.