# How to save response from telnet script?

Tags: linux, bash

I've got my script going as far as It can connect, login and run the command. But I'm stuck as how do I save the response from the command to a file, without saving the whole session.

```
#!/bin/sh
Var=1
while [ $Var -lt 20 ]
do
HOST='IPa.ddr.ess.'$Var
USER='MyUser'
PASSWD='MyPassword'
CMD='MyCommand'

(
    echo open "$HOST"
    sleep 1
    echo "$USER"
    sleep 1
    echo "$PASSWD"
    sleep 1
    echo "$CMD"
    #I want to save the output from my $cmd to an varaible $Output
    #Then I want to write "$HOST - $Output" to a file named "output.txt"
    sleep 2
    echo "exit"
    ) | telnet
Var=$((Var + 1))
done
```

I'd appreciate any help, or pointers in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this looks more challenging than I initially thought. I like it :-)

```
#!/bin/sh
Var=1
while [ $Var -lt 20 ]
do
HOST='IPa.ddr.ess.'$Var
USER='MyUser'
PASSWD='MyPassword'
CMD='MyCommand'
MARKER='XXXX1234:AUIE'

(echo "$HOST - " ; (
    echo unset echo
    echo open "$HOST"
    sleep 1
    echo "$USER"
    sleep 1
    echo "$PASSWD"
    sleep 1
    echo echo "$MARKER"
    echo "$CMD"
    #I want to save the output from my $cmd to an varaible $Output
    #Then I want to write "$HOST - $Output" to a file named "output.txt"
    sleep 2
    echo "exit"
    ) | telnet | sed -e "1,/$MARKER/d" ) >> output.txt
Var=$((Var + 1))
done
```

What this does is:

- it disables echo-ing in telnet
- After the login session, it prints a marker
- anything after the marker is saved into output.txt
- I imbricated into yet another shell that will print the "$HOST -" part

Comment: He doesn't have `$Output` yet; the problem is that `Output=$(... | telnet)` would capture all the authentication and start up, not just the eventual output of the command.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the authentication. I understand the question now. I'll be editing in order to propose the second solution.

Comment: `ssh` is a good idea, if at all possible. It's a good question, though, if the application is on some sort of internal/embedded/legacy device that only provides access via telnet.

Comment: There's always the solution to use expect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27941307/378825

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I only have the option to use telnet, ssh is unfortunately not an option. I will look into expect and see what I can figure out.

Comment: I see now that echo-ing doesn't need to be disabled. You could just skip two lines with sed. OR you just do the non-echo-ing part, it should work but I have no telnet host to test it.

Comment: That script works great, I changed the echo $HOST to echo -n so that it wouldn't make my response and host ip be on different lines.

I also Removed the $MARKER and replaced the sed line with sed -e "1,8d" in order to cut away all the "login lines" e.t.c.

Now a small problem, not a big deal tbh is that if the telnet server is down, I get multiple $HOST -  on the same row, due to my echo -n ofc. 


Is it possible to check if the telnet session is refused if telnet returns "Unable to connect to remote host" and replace it with "$HOST - is down"