# Ansible playbook to telnet a switch from within a switch to update static route

Tags: networking, automation, ansible

We have 2 dedicated vendors that allow connections between two data centers/networks. When one vendor is temporarily unavailable we have to change the static route mapping in both the switches.

**Situation 1: Just after the disconnect**

[image]

**Situation 2: When static route mapping needs to change at Switch A**
[image]

To achieve **Situation 2** we do,

```
$ telnet Switch_A
> no ip route  1.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 20.1.1.1
> add ip route 1.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 30.1.1.1
```

**Situation 3: When static route mapping needs to change at Switch B**
[image]

To achieve **Situation 3** we do,

```
$ telnet Switch_A 
> telnet Switch_B
>> no ip route  2.2.2.0 255.255.255.0 20.1.1.2
>> add ip route 2.2.2.0 255.255.255.0 30.1.1.2
```

Here, I have to telnet to switch B from "within" switch A because Vendor Y is disconnected.

I wrote a following playbook but it gives me error. Please suggest me how can I achieve this using ansible. I cannot use ssh.

```
- name: SHOW VERSION 
  hosts: switch_A
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: show version
      telnet:
        user: userA
        password: *****
        login_prompt: "Username: "
        prompts:
        - '[>|#]'
        command:
          - terminal length 0
          - show version
          - telnet:
              host: 30.1.1.2 // switchB
              user: userB
              password: *****
              login_prompt: "login: "
              prompts:
              - '[>|#]'
              command:
                - terminal length 0
                - show version
```

Error I am getting:

```
TASK [show version] *****************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'
fatal: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Comment: `telnet` module is expecting in the `command` option a list of... commands (i.e. strings that can evaluate to commands you can actually execute). The last element in your list is a dict. If you need to issue an other telnet command inside your telnet module, you need to write it down as if you where in front of your terminal... of find an other way to do it. You may have to upload a script and execute it in this case. But you cannot do this kind of "telnetception".

Comment: What about using wait_for? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html
I never used it with switches but it should work.

`- wait_for:
    host: switchB
    port: 22
    timeout: x
  register: result

- name: do something
  telnet: ...
  when: result.failed | bool`

This should make switchA open a connection to switchB on port 22

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks. But how should I write the playbook in a way as if I were in front of terminal. That exactly the issue I am facing. telnet/shell module in ansible doesn't offer such facility

Comment: @liad9122 when the result will be failed(it always be because it will try to connect switchB using ssh), then we need to make a connection with  switchA using telnet `- name: do something telnet: ...` since tasks in Ansible will exit before picking up the next task. Won't the problem of telnetting switchB via switch A will persist? I have no experience with Ansible. In case I need to read some resource, please help me with some pointers.

Comment: is `expect` available on your switch ?

Comment: You might be interested in the following answer to a question about automating telnet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39804115/9401096

Comment: @Zeitounator expect is not available. For now, I have found a machine which remains connected to the switch via some other vendor. So i ll ssh into that and get the job done.