# Telnet to server, login, and return command result in one line

Tags: linux, routes, command, telnet

I've looked at several other solutions, but none appear to be working the way I need.

I have an embedded controller running Linux (Dreadnaught) and a router also running Linux. I want to read the routing table (just the WAN IP of the default route) of the router, from the controller. My controller has telnet and wget, but does not have ssh or curl. I'd like to do this in a single command with a single result, so I can send the one command from an internal program and parse/save one result.

If I telnet to the router from my PC, either of these two commands gives me the exact result I need:

```
route |grep default|cut -c 17-32
```

or

```
dbctl get route/default/current_gateway
```

Route takes about 30 seconds (not sure why?), even without grep and cut; but dbctl is instant for all intents and purposes.

I've tried the eval method per [Telnet to login with username and password to mail Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941036/telnet-to-login-with-username-and-password-to-mail-server), but that shows all the telnet interactions; I want just the final string result.

I had a poke around at wget, but it looks to be for downloading files, not executing commands.

I'm hoping for:

```
somecommand server=1.2.3.4 user=myuser passwd=MyP@s$ command='dbctl get route/default/current_gateway'
```

which just returns:

```
8.7.6.5
```

Then my internal program (ISaGRAF, but shouldn't be relevant) can send one string to cmd and be returned 1 string, which I can use for my own nefarious purposes (well, I'm just going to log it actually).

If there's absolutely no other way, I can drop a sh script on to the requesting controller, but I'd rather not (extra steps to install, not as portable).

Answer (score 0):

Solved as I was reviewing the question, but looking for suggestions - is this the cleanest method? Could it be done better?

OK, I poked around at the eval method again. Yes, it shows me the full interaction, but it's easy to just get the bits I need, using head and tail:

```
eval "{ sleep 2; echo myuser; sleep 1; echo MyP@s$; sleep 1; echo 'dbctl get route/default/current_gateway'; sleep 2; }" |telnet 1.2.3.4 |head -n 5|tail -n 1
```

eval returns the full interaction:

```
Entering character mode Escape character is '^]'.

login: myuser 
Password: 
admin@myrouter:~# dbctl get route/default/current_gateway
8.7.6.5 
admin@myrouter:~#
```

So I just need head and tail to grab the one line I want using `|head -n 5|tail -n 1`

Comment: Instead of sleep, use expect.